# Detect TWebBrowser refresh event in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, webbrowser-control, refresh

I am using a TWebBrowser component which I  use to load XML documents into which are linked to a XSL file.

I have a default page I display when no XML document is loaded. However, if the user deletes the XML file whilst it is open in the browser and then refreshes I get the standard **resource could not be found** error. What I would like to do instead is if the page cannot be loaded, check that the file exists, and if it doesn't just load the default page again.

I have tried using the [OnNavigateError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268221%28VS.85%29.aspx) and `OnBeforeNavigate2` events however they does not seem to trigger on a refresh.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1):

There is an onRefresh event which is exposed by the TWebBrowser replacement [TEmbeddedWB](http://www.bsalsa.com/product.html).  This version also exposes many other features which are otherwise hidden by the TWebBrowser component.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a cludge but it works in my tests, using the standard TWebBrowser component.

What I did was override the F5 key in the form's `OnKeyUp` event. By setting the form's `KeyPreview` property to True, you can call your own refresh. Seeing as the TWebBrowser.Refresh method doesn't appear to call any of the navigation events (as you said in your question), I call the TWebBrowser.Navigate event myself, which does fire the events.

You need to store the URL, which I imagine you're already doing. But if not, then in the `BeforeNavigate2` event, you are given the `URL` as a parameter. So store this in a variable or on-screen control. Then, when F5 is pressed (or the Refresh button if you have put one on screen), simpy navigate to that URL again. The `OnBeforeNavigate2`, `OnNavigateComplete2` and `OnDocumentComplete` events are all fired again, allowing you the opportunity to perform your test and put your placeholder page up instead of IEs default error page.

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2(Sender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData,
  Headers: OleVariant; var Cancel: WordBool);
begin
  Edit1.Text := URL;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = VK_F5) then
  begin
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(Edit1.Text);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Isn't the contextmenu of TWebBrowser by default enabled? That would mean a user can also refresh via the contextmenu, which bypasses your check on F5.  Samradts suggestion of a replacement control that does surface the OnRefresh event seems better in that case.